# React class component not re-rendering after fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

In my React application, the user clicks a button which triggers the handleAdd() function, which adds the item to the users cart on the server.  After the fetch, I'm calling getCartSummary() to grab the updated cart and re-render the components.  But, it only works 80% of the time.  Console logs indicate that getCartSummary() runs before handleAdd() has had time to finish updating the back end.  In this case, I have to manually refresh the page to see the updated components.  This can't be that hard, what am I misunderstanding about the React paradigm?

````
getCartSummary = () => {
    fetch(`/api/order/cart/summary`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')}
      })
      .then(this.checkError)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          cartCount : data.count,
          cartPrice : data.price
        },console.log(data.count, data.price))
      })
  }
      
  handleAdd = (itemID) => {
    fetch(`/api/order/add/${itemID}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')}
    })
    .then(this.checkError)
    .then(this.getCartSummary())
  }
  }```
````

Comment: is there any other place where you call ```getCartSummary``` other than in ```handleAdd``` function?

Comment: In your handleAdd function you are *calling* `getCartSummary` *at the time the function is defined*. Get rid of the extra parens if you mean to pass it as a callback to `.then`.

Answer (score 0):

The line `.then(this.getCartSummary())` is running getCartSummary immediately.
It should be `.then(this.getCartSummary)` which will call getCartSummary after handleAdd is finished.

Comment: Oh damn.  The things you learn late at night after looking at something all day. Thank you so much!